# Name of .cs file not changing in a vs2008 project created through my custom template?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I created a template from a vs2008 project in C#.In the "MyTemplate.vstemplate" file,I added the following to replace the name of the .cs file to "wds.cs":

```
<TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="WPF1.csproj" File="WPF1.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="mycode.cs">WPF1.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>

  </TemplateContent>
```

But after creating a project from this template..the resulting project shows the file "WPF1.cs" instead of showing "mycode.cs"???????

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly which one of **$itemname$** or **"$fileinputname$.cs** you'd want to use as your target file name, but you need to use replaceable parameters.

- [Visual Studio 2008 Template Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [Item Template Creation](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309093226/http://www.switchonthecode.com:80/tutorials/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates) (item templates, but shows the **ProjectItem** node where you need to do the substitution.